# Correct way to export individual, common JS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a npm module that uses common js modules, but I'm having difficultly referencing the modules.

The directory structure:

```
\ my-project
  package.json
  test.js
  \lib
    index.js
    client.js
    my-error.js
```

`client.js`:

```
class Client {
}
module.exports = Client
```

`my-error.js`:

```
class MyError extends Error {
}
module.exports = MyError
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "@foo/my-project",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  ...
}
```

`index.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync('./lib').forEach(function(file){
    if ( file.indexOf(".js") > -1 && file != "index.js" ) 
        exports[ file.replace('.js','') ] = require('./'+file);
});
```

This works, but exports are named after the file, not the class itself.

`test.js`:

```
require('./lib')

try {
    const client = new Client()
    ...
}
```

When I run the script, I get an error:

```
$ node ./test.js

ReferenceError - Client is not defined
```

How do I correctly reference the modules that are exported by `/lib/index.js`?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Hi.  What would be the need to have a dynamic enumeration of files?  Why the need to create the exports dynamically?  After all, the package will be finite once deployed.

Comment: Just guessing - is it because 'exports[ file.replace('.js','') ]'  uses a string name 'file' whereas when you do exports.myFunction = myFunction then exports.**myFunction** is a key and not a string?

Comment: @JoséRamírez, how does the package know to load all of the files in the `/lib` directory?

Comment: Why would `Client` be defined in *test.js*? You did neither import it nor is it a global variable

Comment: Don't try to do anything fancy with `fs.readdirSync('./lib')`. Just write `exports.Client = require('./client'); exports.MyError = require('./my-error');`. Much simpler, much shorter, more readable, assigns the proper names instead of guessing, and can be correctly analysed by bundlers and by ESM imports.

Comment: Simple:  Do `require()` of individual classes by hand, then export them.  There's no need for a dynamic algorithm.  Have 3 classes?  Import them in index, then export them.

Comment: @Bergi, keep the `module.exports = X` in each module file, add `exports.Client = require('./client'); exports.MyError = require('./my-error');` to `/lib/index.js`, then add `require('./lib')` to each script file that needs these classes?

Comment: @craig You also need to use `const { Client } = require('./lib')` in the *test.js* module to be able to access the class by the name `Client` in that scope. Otherwise yes.